# avahi set hostname but arp -a only displays IP

Tags: debian, zeroconf, mdns, avahi

I've set my

```
/etc/hosts
```

and

```
/etc/hostname
```

on my Debian system. 
I also have the Avahi daemon installed and running.

From my mac I run

```
arp -a
```

and this lists all the IP's but where the hostname should be I see a

```
?
```

How can I get Avahi to broadcast my hostname?

Comment: The question that pops up for me: Does `arp` even attempt to resolve names with mDNS?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ip -r neigh`, `arp` utility is now obsolete. See [net-tools](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/net-tools) . This one support mdns name resolution by using glibc's name service switch. Therefore you need to have

```
mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]
```

in the `hosts:` line of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

If you're using IPv6, don't forget to set

```
use-ipv6=yes
```

in `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` and check that your machines use

```
mdns_minimal
```

and not

```
mdns4_minimal
```

in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.